# System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException on a string value

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, serialization

I have a WCF REST service that is returning a business object that contains a string field called 'GeoDataKML'.  This field is just a string value, but it has KML string inside it (encoded, so that it doesn't interfere with XML serialization of this business object).  The problem is that when this field has data in it, i get a WCF error trying to download this data:

System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

The data i'm trying to send is below.  If i blank out the GeoDataKML value, then the service works fine, no errors.  Applying KnownType doesn't seem to do any good.  Any ideas on how to get WCF REST to NOT try to serialize the data in this string object?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?><ArrayOfFullLogEntry xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <FullLogEntry>
    <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
    <StaticGUID>be547685-2bdd-4abf-84a4-d20c13c5fe58</StaticGUID>
    <GeoDataKML>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?&gt;&lt;kml xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"&gt;&lt;Placemark id="7e5272b6-d1b4-4128-95bf-24ea9358681a"&gt;&lt;name&gt;CasualtyTool&lt;/name&gt;&lt;styleUrl&gt;#CasualtyTool&lt;/styleUrl&gt;&lt;Point&gt;&lt;altitudeMode&gt;clampToGround&lt;/altitudeMode&gt;&lt;coordinates&gt;-115.594205424414,41.295597016765,5000&lt;/coordinates&gt;&lt;/Point&gt;&lt;/Placemark&gt;&lt;/kml&gt;</GeoDataKML>
    <SymbolGUID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</SymbolGUID>
    <GeoDataTypeGUID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</GeoDataTypeGUID>....
```

FullLogEntry only has these values:

```
public class FullLogEntry
{
public Guid StaticGUID {get;set;}
public string GeoDataKML {get;set;}
public Guid GeoDataTypeGUID{get;set;}
public Guid SymbolGUID{get;set;}
public bool IsSelected {get;set;}
}
```

service contract is just:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = WCFServiceBaseClass.ServiceNamespace)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, Namespace = WCFServiceBaseClass.ServiceNamespace)]
```

where the namespace is 'http://test.org'

Comment: So it can be serializend but not deserialized, correct? Please add the WCF ServiceContract interfac and the FullLogEntry class to your post.

Comment: i can serialize/deserialize via XML without any problems.  It's only on the WCF REST service that i am getting any issues.  See above for the class and contract.  Nothing special to either.

Comment: Ah. Sorry by servicecontract I meant the interface not just the attributes. What do you mean by serialize/deserialized via XML? XmlSerializer, Datacontractserializer,...?

Comment: xmlserializer.  There is no interface, it's WCF REST 4 so i'm just returning a generic List of those FullLogEntry objects, nothing special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to add

```
<System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownType(GetType(PlacemarkType))> _
```

at the top of the fulllogentry class.  works now!